# jaxb override package of a specific generated set of classes

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a large third party xsd file that pulls in a whole bunch of other xsd files through imports. The whole thing generates over 1000 classes. When I tell the xjc (jaxb) processor to generate everything in a specific package I get all kinds of naming conflicts. If I don't specify a package, then the processor creates java packages using the target attributes in the xsd files, and the whole thing generates without any errors.

The problem is that the package structure is awful because the target names are chosen really poorly. Other developers hate it. They only need a few classes.

So what I've been trying to do is to give the processor a bindings.xml file where I want to specify certain classes to be generated in a given package name.
I've gone back and forth between documentation on Oracle's site, forums, samples. I can't quote every single iteration of my bindings file. My current incarnation is this:

```
<jaxb:bindings 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1"
    schemaLocation="heavy.xsd"
    node="//xsd:element[@name='Error']"
>

    <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:element[@name='Error']">
        <jaxb:package name="ABC"/>
    </jaxb:bindings>

    <jaxb:globalBindings
        underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"
        localScoping="toplevel"
        typesafeEnumMaxMembers="10000"
        generateElementClass="true"
    >
    </jaxb:globalBindings>


<!--
        <jaxb:package name="ABC"/>
-->

<!--
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="ABC"/>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
-->

<!--
    <jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:package name="ABC"/>
        <jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
            <jaxb:elementName prefix="Error"/>
        </jaxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jaxb:schemaBindings>
-->

</jaxb:bindings>
```

No matter what I try, I have not yet seen it generate any classes in the ABC package. In this case I want Error to get generated in ABC. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you found any way to do this, I am interested by your solution.

Answer (score 4):

The way I would do it is more like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jxb:bindings xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="2.1" jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="XSD1.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <!-- -->
        </jxb:globalBindings>
        <jxb:schemaBindings xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
            <jxb:package name="com.something">
            </jxb:package>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
        <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='Error']">
            <jxb:class xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" name="MyError"/>
            <jxb:property xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" name="Whatever"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
    <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="XSD2.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <jxb:schemaBindings xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc">
            <jxb:package name="com.somethingelse">
            </jxb:package>
        </jxb:schemaBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Why do you duplicate `xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"` across XML? Isn't it easier to put it to root element?

Comment: The snippet comes from a bindings file that is automatically generated by a tool, hence the "sub-optimal" use of XML namespaces.

Comment: If I'm understanding this bindings file correctly, it tells all generated java files from XSD1.xsd to be in the com.something package,  renames the Error class to MyError, and all generated java files from XSD2.xsd in the com.somethingelse package. Is that correct?
But what I'm trying puzzle out is how to put one specific element in a specific package, while all the other elements go into their normal package names. I need to override one specific element.

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your understanding. I am not aware of a way to control package name for individual classes. What I would do in your case, if I would *must have* to do it (disclaimer: I am biased here by the tools that I am using) would be to isolate whatever content I want in a specific java package, in a separate XSD file - practically introduce one or more <xsd:include/>s. This way, it'll work, if you need to make it work. Also, in the process, the same tool I am using, would be able to remove any unused XSD content (as scoped by your implementation), thus cutting down the classes

Comment: Not everyone has control of the XSDs. And they might change in the future if you parse them. I'm looking for the same answer.

Comment: @JustinDennahower, I don't understand your comment... Refactoring XSDs is particularly for those scenarios where one doesn't have control of how XSDs are released, and one needs to do things as described in the question. Automatic refactoring minimizes the overhead required to maintain adherence to future changes without manually splitting the original XSDs over and over again.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it is not possible to do what you want. I want the same thing and I'm in the same boat. But straight from Oracles mouth:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnbbt/index.html

**Relevant Info:**

> name - is the name of the derived Java interface. It must be a legal Java interface name and must not contain a package prefix. The package prefix is inherited from the current value of package.

So there is simply no way on the  element to specify a different package its inherited per xsd.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example of bindings.xjb file where java source is generated in primer.myPo package.

```
<jxb:bindings version="1.0"
               xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <jxb:bindings schemaLocation="po.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <jxb:globalBindings
         fixedAttributeAsConstantProperty="false"
         collectionType="java.util.Vector"
         typesafeEnumBase="xs:NCName"
         choiceContentProperty="false"
         typesafeEnumMemberName="generateError"
         enableFailFastCheck="false"   
         generateIsSetMethod="false"
         underscoreBinding="asCharInWord"/>
    <jxb:schemaBindings>
      <jxb:package name="primer.myPo">
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[<body>Package level documentation for generated package primer.myPo.</body>]]>
</jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:package>
      <jxb:nameXmlTransform>
        <jxb:elementName suffix="Element"/>
      </jxb:nameXmlTransform>
    </jxb:schemaBindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='PurchaseOrderType']">
      <jxb:class name="POType">
        <jxb:javadoc>A &lt;b>Purchase Order&lt;/b> consists of addresses and items.</jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:class>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='USAddress']">
      <jxb:class>
        <jxb:javadoc><![CDATA[First line of documentation for a <b>USAddress</b>.]]></jxb:javadoc>
      </jxb:class>

      <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='name']">
        <jxb:property name="toName"/>
      </jxb:bindings>

      <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='zip']">
         <jxb:property name="zipCode"/>
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings> <!-- node="//xs:complexType[@name='USAddress']" -->

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='Items']">
      <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='item']//xs:element[@name='quantity']">
        <jxb:property generateIsSetMethod="true"/>

        <jxb:bindings node="./xs:simpleType">
          <jxb:javaType name="short" 
                        parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseShort" 
                        printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printShort" />
        </jxb:bindings>
      </jxb:bindings>  <!--  node="//xs:complexType[@name='Items']" -->

      <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='USPrice']">
        <jxb:property name="Price"/>
      </jxb:bindings>

      <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:attribute[@name='partNum']">
        <jxb:property name="partNumber"/>
      </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='USState']">
      <jxb:typesafeEnumClass/>
    </jxb:bindings>

    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:simpleType[@name='ZipCodeType']">
      <jxb:javaType name="int"     
                    parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseInt" 
                    printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printInt"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
  </jxb:bindings> <!-- schemaLocation="po.xsd" node="/xs:schema" -->

</jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: I think that this makes po.xsd generated content in the primer.myPro package for any element that ends with the Element name?
Second, it renames the class from a complexType with the name PurchaseOrderType to POType as its new class name. I've also discovered how to rename a specific class. If only there was a way to have that class go in a specific package, which is what I'm after. I'm not getting the remaining parts. It's setting properties based on xpath matched elements, attributes, and simpleTypes? But then what?

Comment: That isn't the answer to his question. He wants to map one particular element to a difference package not by xsd.